# I've just got the darkrai code but lost the instructions... Any help?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

Title says it all basically. Lost instructions for darkrai. I've got the codes (remembered to write them down). Do I need to validate it or something? Sorry, I know I'm quite hopeless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to go to:

1. **Mystery Gift** window at the main menu
2. Receive Gift and agree to open communication channel
3. Get With Code and agree to connect to internet
4. Enter your serial code and press End

If the code is valid, you will be told that it's valid and there's a pokemon waiting for you in a Poke Center.

Sometimes if you are redeeming a code the same day an event has started, it might not work and you should wait until later that day or tomorrow and try again.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I will update this with screenshots in a bit, when I get to my 3ds.

Comment: I've done this but it says its invalid... I've tried reentering but to nno avail, wrong code then?

Comment: Either it's invalid code or Nintendo hasn't activated the codes yet. You should try later today or tomorrow. If it doesn't work tomorrow, it might be an invalid code.

Comment: My brother has the same problem, hes got a 15 digit code, is he missing a digit?

Comment: If both of you are having an issue, it's most likely an issue on Nintendo's half. It's not the first time when their pokemon codes don't work on the first day.

Comment: Finally works, cheers, youve beebeen a great help. Would commend ypu but dont have enough reputation or summin.

Comment: You can upvote the answer, if you haven't already, but other than that, you've done all you could to thank me :P I'm glad I could help!